# Firebase restrict browser api key to localhost and what if a hacker does the same

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, localhost

I learn Firebase and see under the [Firebase console apis](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/) i can and I must of course restrict the key to my website domain only.

But what or how do I handle when I have two Firebase apps like Developement and Production. The Development App is then restricted to my localhost.

But then anyone can use my api key in their own localhost or?

[image]